# Looking for a Chemistry Demo Resource Group

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I'm looking for some kind of email list, forum, or group that discusses chemistry demonstrations. I'm working on an improvement to a demo that's been used for a few decades at my institution and I'm looking for a other few people (that aren't at my institution) to try it out and give feedback. Any ideas?